# Android Rertifit : POST Multiple 2D Arrays

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, postman, retrofit2

can you help me. I have a problem how to send data in the form of a 2D array on android studio using retrofit. I attached a postman example.
Thanks all.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(ApiEndpoint.ENDPOINT_SERVER_POST_VISUAL_INSPECTION_REGISTER)
fun apiService(
    @Field("visual_inspection_register_id[0]") visualInspectionRegisterId: List<String?>,
    @Field("visual_inspection_register_uuid[0][1]") visualInspectionRegisterUUID: List<String?>,
    @Field("visual_inspection_register_geom[0][1]") visualInspectionRegisterGeom: List<String?>
): Observable<BaseResponse>
```

more or less like this when it will be sent

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHJsU.png)

Comment: Please consider providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Send it as a JSON string `[ [ { } ], [ {  } ], ]` and parse it using `JSON.parse(req.body.your_array)`.

Comment: @mightyWOZ thanks for correcting my question i will fix it soon.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar Thanks I will try it